# If $X$ is exponentially distributed, what is $\Pr (\sin X > \frac{1}{2})$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know how to work out things in the form $\Pr(\mbox{g}(X) < x)$ for $X \sim \mbox{Exp}(\lambda)$, but only if $\mbox{g}$ is a strictly increasing differentiable function. $\sin$ isn't strictly increasing, so I'm not sure how to go about finding $\Pr (\sin X > \frac{1}{2})$.

Any help on how to do this sort of problem generally would be appreciated.

Comment: Given the periodicity of the sine function and the memorylessness of the exponential distribution this will be $\dfrac{P\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6} \lt X \lt \dfrac{5\pi}{6}\right)}{P\left(0 \le X \lt 2\pi\right)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality $\sin x > \frac{1}{2}$ is eqivalent to $x \in \left( 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{6},\,2n\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6} \right)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. For each $n\geq 0$, $$\int_{2n\pi + \pi /6}^{2n\pi + 5\pi /6} \lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x}\text{d}x=\left[ 1-\text{e}^{-\lambda x} \right]_{2n\pi + \pi /6}^{2n\pi + 5\pi /6} = \text{e}^{-2n\pi\lambda} \left(\text{e}^{-\pi\lambda /6}-\text{e}^{-5\pi\lambda /6}\right).$$ Summing over $n \geq 0$ gives $$\text{Pr}\left( \sin X > \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{\text{e}^{-\pi\lambda /6}-\text{e}^{-5\pi\lambda /6}}{1-\text{e}^{-2\pi\lambda}}.$$